# React Redux Props Undefined During Variable Assignment

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why is it when I assign the props to a JSX variable, it outputs as undefined? Is this normal? Or is there some other code in my program that would be causing this issue?

```
const { foo } = this.props;
console.log(this.props);
console.log(foo);
```

[image: screenshot of output]

```
class Library extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
    M.AutoInit();
  }
  render() {
    const { foo } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(foo);
    return <div className="container"></div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cred: state.cred.tabs
  };
};
```

Comment: Could you give any more context? What is the rest of the component? How are you passing props into it?

Comment: I don't see any `foo` key in `this.props` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) property `foo` from `this.props`.
But according to your logs, `this.props` does not seem to contain any `foo` property.

Answer (score 0):

`const { foo } = this.props;` is the same as writing `const foo = this.props.foo;`, which, it seems, is not a value in your props.

If that's not intended and you are instead trying to assign the whole props object to the foo variable, the correct syntax would be `const foo = this.props;`.